# Create line segments from GeoJot Points

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I would like to create numerous line segments from a set of GeoJot points. Is there a way I should format the data so I can run a script; and is there a script that can accomplish this? I have coordinates (geotagged photos) for Intersection "A" and "B" and would like to link them with a line that would then have the data form from the point (deplicate data form for "A" and "B" except one says "begin" and the other "end"; I don't care about this field, so could use either point). I have done an entire community this way and it is tedious to create new segments by manually inserting a line between the points, moving the data form to the line and then deleting the points.

Answer (score 2):

Are your "GeoJot" point created from a GPS unit?  Are they in a shapefile or feature class?  There is a "point to line tool" in ArcToolbox that would work with your points in those formats? You shouldn't need a script.